# npm ENOSELF error - installing a package in its gh-pages branch

Tags: npm, github-pages, conventions

I'd like to write some documentation for a JS Lib on GitHub, using the Lib itself. I created an empty branch called `gh-pages` and started building the documentation pages. Now I need to write some Javascript using the Lib I'm documenting, because who wouldn't use their own Library. I tried installing it via `npm install` but obviously got this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "package" under a package
npm ERR! also called "package". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>
```

So how do I get my codebase into my `gh-pages`-branch **without** copying it from the master branch? I do not want to maintain the same codebase in two different branches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For instance, I could just rename the package name property in my `package.json` in the branch...

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same problem. I find that I make the name same with package name in `package.json`. I was installing nodemailer and here given same name that was my mistake:

[image: error-picture]

So make sure your name is different from the package you are installing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call your project same name into package.json, else your installation doesn't work!

[image]