# Why npm install redux does not install?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, redux

```
PS D:\PracticeRDX> npm install redux
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "redux" under a package
npm ERR! also called "redux". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-27T15_10_10_560Z-debug.log
PS D:\PracticeRDX>
```

Comment: Check your `package.json` file. Choose a name that does not crash with any of your dependencies.

Comment: your project directory or project name is same as the package name

Comment: I also think this is only a limitation in npm version 6 or less. If you upgrade to the latest npm, you can call your project `redux` if you like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ENOSELF error - installing a package in its gh-pages branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534247/npm-enoself-error-installing-a-package-in-its-gh-pages-branch)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the latest npm version (v7). As mention in the logs, try with npm install --legacy-peer-deps.

Comment: This error `ENOSELF` was removed in npm cli 7. And the current latest npm cli is version 8. OP is presumably using npm cli 6 or earlier.